# Translating SqlAlchemy group_by/func query to GraphQL

Tags: sqlalchemy, graphql, graphene-python

I am using Graphene and SqlAlchemy to build GraphQL queries for a cafe ordering app.  Until now my queries have mostly been "join" and "filter" based, but I now need to provide the cafe with customer details, including the number of times the customer has visited their shop and the customer's average spend per visit.  So I have needed to use group_by, func.count and func.sum in my Graphene/SqlAlchemy queries.  These queries have been successful enough.  However, I am unsure of how to translate the Graphene/SqlAlchemy query into a GraphQL one.

Here is my Graphene/SqlAlchemy query.

```
        cafe_customers = db.query(models.Customer.username, func.count(models.Order.ordered_by), func.sum(models.Order.price)).join(models.Order, models.Customer.id == models.Order.ordered_by).filter(models.Order.cafe_id == current_user).group_by(models.Customer.id).all()
```

Here is my GraphQL query (which I am very unsure about how to conduct).

```
{
  customersByCafe(token: "") {
    username
  }
}
```

This is what I am being returned by GraphQL.

```
{
  "data": {
    "customersByCafe": [
      null,
      null
    ]
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Received incompatible instance \"('dave', 1, Decimal('11.00'))\"."
    },
    {
      "message": "Received incompatible instance \"('geoff', 2, Decimal('50.00'))\"."
    }
  ]
}
```

There is a similar question on here relating to the "reception of incompatible instance in graphql query", where the solution was to change graphene.Field to graphene.List.  My query is set to graphene.List and I have played around with different options. Noting that GraphQL is returning to me the data I require, which is each customer grouped by username, an integer of their total visits to the cafe whose account is signed into and a decimal of their total spend, there is the obvious error of the data not being returned in a fashion I can work with on my front end.

It seems my problem lies in the fact that I do not know how to translate the Graphene/SqlAlchemy into GraphQL.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Received incompatible instance "('dave', 1, Decimal('11.00'))"
What you are receiving is a list of tuples, from your SqlAlchemy query, you should be returning a list of objects/dictionary instead.

Also you should have mentioned your schema here.